# How to create a exe file from jar file for database application in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have create a database application that is login base . I have completed this project. and I was used a phpMyAdmin for database. but the problem is that how I can create a exe file for end users. How to build MySQL database file in Java project to create a exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is not an embedded databsse. Rather than using standalone DBMS's(MySQL) you can use lightweight DBMS's such as SQLite, Firebird and embedded databases made in Java like H2, HSQL, Derby and etc.

Anyhow,

If you want MySQL you can use **[Connector/MXJ](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-mxj/)**.
You can read [this blog](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/How-To-Embed-Mysql-Database-Into-Java-Application) to see how to use this.

There is several ways(or softwares) you can use to create exe. I am using the following method.

Download [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) to create **exe** from **jar**.
then using **exe4j** you can include jar and add your info and setup. Like the below images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you want more help to use exe4j you can reffer to this video. [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJHFLG2Ovo0)

Answer (score 1):

Jar2exe is a nice tool for your requirement
http://www.jar2exe.com/
Try that out.